# Insertar Venta y detalle de venta con Transacciones en mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy intentando de guardar una venta y el detalle con transacciones en mysql desde php usando mysqli pero no he podido intente colocarlo dentro de un try catch pero no me funciona

```
         try{ 
                    $conexion->autocommit(FALSE);
                    $error = true;
//ESTA ES LA PRIMERA INSERCION     
                        $sql="INSERT INTO tblentradas(entNroFactura,
                                                      entTotal,
                                                      entFecha, 
                                                      entProveedor, 
                                                      entEstado, 
                                                      entUsuario) 
                              VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $result=$conexion->consulta($sql,'sdsiii',array($NfacturaC,$total,$fecha,$proveedor,$estado,$RUser));
                        if ( !$result) { $error = false; }
 
// SEGUNDA INSERCION LA REALIZO CON UN FOR QUE RECORRE UNA VARIABLE DE SESSION PARA EL DETALLE DE VENTA                 
                         session_start();
                          $datos=($_SESSION['carritoCompras']);
                            
           for ($i=0; $i < count($datos); $i++) {   
              $detalleEntrada = new ClsDetalleEntrada(null, $NfacturaC,$datos[$i]['idArt'],
                $datos[$i]['Cantidad'], $datos[$i]['valorArt'], $datos[$i]['valVenta'], $datos[$i]['FV']);
                  $resul = self::guardarDetalleEntrada($detalleEntrada);
                  if ( !$resul) { $error = false; }
            }
            
                              if ($error) {
                                $conexion->commit();
                              }else{
                                $conexion->rollback();
                              }
                          
                
      } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
          $conexion->rollback();
          throw $e;
      }
```

tengo una función guardarDetalleEntrada que se encarga de insertar los datos en la BD, las dos funciones insertan los datos correctamente en la BD, pero modifique la segunda consulta para que me arroje error y al colocarla dentro de la transacción no me esta capturando el error e inserta en la primera tabla pero en la segunda no y deberia de no insertar datos en ninguna

estas son la funciones que estoy utilizando mySQLI contiene la conexión a la base de datos

```
public function transaction(){
    $this->transaction = $this->mySQLI->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);
    return $this->transaction;
  }

  public function autocommit($var){
    $this->autocommit = $this->mySQLI->autocommit($var);
    return $this->autocommit;
  }

  public function commit(){
    $this->commit = $this->mySQLI->commit();
    return $this->commit;
  }

  public function rollback(){
    $this->rollback = $this->mySQLI->rollback();
    return $this->rollback;
  }
```

Comment: No logro entender tu código, sobre todo esta parte: `if ($error) { $conexion->commit(); }else{ $conexion->rollback();}` ¿Haces el `commit` cuando hay error y el `rollback` cuando no hay error? Debería ser justo lo contrario.

Comment: Hola @A. Cedeno gracias por responder NO en el if pregunto si `$error` existe o es true ejecuta el `commit` de lo contrario ejecute `rollback` ya que anteriormente a la variable $error le estor cambiando a false cuando no se ejecuta la consulta en `if ( !$resul) { $error = false; }`

Comment: que otra forma o como puedo mejorar este codigo?